# MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE not valid in call to getSystemService()

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, screen-capture

I am trying to develop an application that requires the ability to capture screen content. I'm targeting  lollipop to avoid the requirement for root.  When trying to get an instance of the MediaProjectionManager via a call to getSystemService() I am getting the following error reported in Android Studio:

```
Must be one of: Context.POWER_SERVICE, Context.WINDOW_SERVICE, Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE, Context.ACCOUNT_SERVICE, Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE, Context.ALARM_SERVICE, Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE, Context.CAPTIONING_SERVICE, Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE, Context.LOCATION_SERVICE, Context.SEARCH_SERVICE, Context.SENSOR_SERVICE, Context.STORAGE_SERVICE, Context.WALLPAPER_SERVICE, Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE, Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE, Context.WIFI_SERVICE, Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE, Context.NSD_SERVICE, Context.AUDIO_SERVICE, Context.MEDIA_ROUTER_SERVICE, Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE, Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE, Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE, Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE, Context.DROPBOX_SERVICE, Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE, Context.UI_MODE_SERVICE, Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE, Context.NFC_SERVICE, Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE, Context.USB_SERVICE, Context.INPUT_SERVICE, Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE, Context.USER_SERVICE, Context.PRINT_SERVICE less... (Ctrl+F1) 

Reports two types of problems:
* Supplying the wrong type of resource identifier. For example, when calling Resources.getString(int id), you should be passing R.string.something, not R.drawable.something.
* Passing the wrong constant to a method which expects one of a specific set of constants. For example, when calling View#setLayoutDirection, the parameter must be android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR or android.view.View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL.
```

I am currently at a loss as to why this constant is not considered valid, it's there as an autocomplete option, so it's present, and it's shown in all sample code I have seen for screen capture in lollipop.  I have verified that the project setup specifies Android SDK 21 as min and target. Is there something else obvious/stupid I might be missing that would cause this error?

UPDATE:  Took the exact same code to Eclipse and it works without issue. So this is related to something in Android Studio specifically it seems.

Answer (score 2):

I get this error while getting `Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE`and the error doc (*Must be one of..*) contains `Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE` though.

This is not the way Android Studio "1.2" should work. :@

Anyway, its an `Inspection` bug, `Constant and Resource Type mismatch` (How in the hell Bluetooth is a resource in android context).

You can suppress this for Class/Method/Statement, for statement, add `@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")` above or before the statement.

Another approach:

Goto ***Settings>>Editor>>Inspection>>Android>>Constant and Resource Type Mismatches*** and make the severity to anything but `Error`, probably `Warning` or `Weak Warning`.

(Though it fixes the error issue, but I want this mismatch to be an error when it really happens.)

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same problem, it is so strange, there are no any other threads talking about this problem. 
Well, actually you can just ignore this error and still run the program, even with 
the red marks on it